# Retrieve name as variable on POST

Tags: php, mysql, variables

I have a DB, in this DB i have a table called question, then another table called q_options. My code brings the questions and then the options for each question. The options are always radio BTNs and i assign the questionId to the name of the radio BTN.

```
<input type = "radio" name = "<?php echo $optionsQID; ?>" value = "<?php echo $optionsID; ?>">
```

That part right there is the one i can't get to my DB. when i print_r my POST i can see the field with the assigned number is been posted but i can't retrieve it from `$qAnswer = $_POST[$optionsQID];` after submit.

I have tried with the quotes and without the quotes, i also tried adding and identifier to the radio BTN name along with the variable but i still don't get the value of that field.

I also moved the entire

```
if (isset($_POST["answerQuestion"])){
            $question = $_POST["questionID"];
            $qAnswer = $_POST[$optionsQID];    

            $sql = "INSERT INTO answers (id, q_id, answer) 
            VALUES (NULL, '$question', '$qAnswer')";

            echo "Thanks for your input";

            if(!mysqli_query($link, $sql)) {
                echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
            }
        }
```

inside the second while loop and this sends the correct value of $qAnswer but then also creates a record for each of the questions.

This is my code

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST["answerQuestion"])){
        $question = $_POST["questionID"];
        $qAnswer = $_POST[$optionsQID];    

        $sql = "INSERT INTO answers (id, q_id, answer) 
        VALUES (NULL, '$question', '$qAnswer')";

        echo "Thanks for your input";

        if(!mysqli_query($link, $sql)) {
            echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
        }
    }
    ?>
    <?php $questionsResult = $link->query("SELECT * FROM questions");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($questionsResult)){
        $questionID = $row['id'];
        $question = $row['question'];

        ?>
        <div style = "margin: 20px 10%; padding: 50px 10%; width: 60%; border: 1px solid #444444;">
            <form role="form" action = "" method="post" id="answerForm" name = "answerForm">
                <h3><?php echo $question; ?></h3>
                <input type = "hidden" name = "questionID" value = "<?php echo $questionID; ?>">
                <?php

                $optionsResult = $link->query("SELECT * FROM q_options WHERE q_id = $questionID");
                while($optionsRow = mysqli_fetch_array($optionsResult)){
                    $optionsID = $optionsRow['id'];
                    $optionsQID = $optionsRow['q_id'];
                    $option = $optionsRow['options'];
                    ?>
                    <div style = "padding: 5px 0;">
                        <input type = "radio" name = "<?php echo $optionsQID; ?>" value = "<?php echo $optionsID; ?>"> <?php echo $option; ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                }
                ?>
                <button type="submit" name = "answerQuestion">Send Answer</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <?php
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: @TheCodesee you seem not to see that `variable name` and `variable content` are two different things. what the point of quotes?

Comment: The variable `$optionsQID` is not defined within the isset($_POST['answerQuestion']) section because you don't declare it til later on.  Enable error reporting at the top of your file with `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: I have to add that if i move the entire if (isset($_POST["answerQuestion"])){] inside the second while loop it will post the value of $qAnswer the problem here is it will create a record for each question even though these extra records will have value NULL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what i did in order to get this working and move on. At least while i finish the proof of concept.

I moved the `if (isset($_POST["answerQuestion"])){` inside the loop that brings my questions, since all variables are defined by then i get my values passed on POST, this creates a problem that it will create a record for every question even if they are not answered by the user. I solve this new problem by deleting those extra records without an answer value. It is a dirty solution but it takes so little time i'm going with it for now until someone give me a better way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are running the script on a server either local (using XAMPP) or on a host online. A few days ago I had a similar issue with POST data from my Ajax request to my PHP file and that resolved it after hours of googling. I could be wrong but just make sure you are running it on a server (if you want to try on a free live host you can use 000webhost)

Links
https://www.000webhost.com/
https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html

Comment: I am running on MAMP and everything works except for this one variable i can't pass. Thanks